# Estimation of the last digit of $\frac{\sqrt{m!+1}-1}{10}$

Tags: number-theory

$\frac{\sqrt{m!+1}-1}{10}$
Can you write a formula to work out the numbers surrounding the decimal point?
For example when $m=11$ it equals $631.6974438...$ so it would be $1.6$

Comment: For $m=11$ your expression is $6316.974438$, no?

Comment: @lulu I got the same answer by it was divided by 10

Comment: Right, I didn't divide by $10$.  But by point was that the numbers that surround the decimal are $1.6$, no?

Comment: Yeah they are. I'll edit it.

Comment: Regardless...what sort of formula are you hoping for?  The numbers look unpromising.

Comment: @lulu (Calling it $f (x) $)Exploiting the fact that the decimal points of  $f(x)$ = $\frac{\sqrt{m!}}{10}$ for big enough  $m $.

Comment: I think this is also $(\lfloor \sqrt{m!+1}-1 \rfloor \pmod {100} )/10$